# Midi-dot-net sounds played twice

Tags: c#, midi, midi-instrument

Firstable I am not a PRO programmer but only a student who hava a little problem with an excelent library Midi-Dot-Net.

I use a Midi-Dot-Net library to write a simple application in Visual Studio in C# language. But I stuck on a very confusing problem.

I placed a little code into Form1.cs

```
public void NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg) {
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        BeginInvoke(noteOnHandler, msg);
        return;
    }

     inputStatusLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}", msg.Pitch);
     String nutka = inputStatusLabel.Text;

    if (nutka == "A0") {
        clock.Schedule(new NoteOnMessage(outputDevice, Channel.Channel1, Pitch.A0, 80, 2));
    }
}
```

So, I placed new String and called it nutka, and nutka will receive name of the pressed note on my USB MIDI Keyboard. Then I placed IF statment, and compared nutka to "A0" (first note on the keyboard).

Then if it's "A0" I pressed my outputDevice plays specific note. And it plays but it plays twice, one - when I press key (with note A0) on keyboard and second time - when I release that key.

I did a breakpoint on `public void NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg)` and noticed that an application returns here twice and plays twice that note, still don't know why.

One more thing, there is a method `public void NoteOff(NoteOffMessage message)`, but it seems not working.

I really can't figure it out, and I'm looking for any help.

**UPDATE**
**...
UPDATE
...**
**UPDATE**

Another problem appears (the first part was resolved thanks to **CL** and  **Chris Dunaway** advice and step-by-step **Justin** explanation).

Thank you Justin :) i see life without any problems is not possible :)

With `clock.Schedule` i can play only the MIDI sound but i want to play example piano notes (wav file format) and in 4-5 
weeks my college will help me recording my own piano sounds for every note. I also want to play them simultaneous.

I thought everything will be just fine and now... got problem with simultaneous playing. I was trying to check three possibilities:

**1) I was trying to play piano sounds from basic notes library i have and use SoundPlayer for it:**

```
SoundPlayer noteA0 = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.A0);
noteA0.Play();
```

i use it for every note statement with different SoundPlayer name (depend on note name) and what i noticed is - i can't play notes simultaneously.

**2) so i used next WMP library and WindowsMediaPlayer:**

for example:

```
var noteA0 = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
noteA0.URL = @"c:\sounds\piano\A0.wav";
```

Ok... it plays simultaneous but it looks like the more notes i play or i just play a song the bigger latency i got and finnaly my programm stuck on playing anything...

**3) i was trying to use Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback:**

```
Audio noteA1 = new Audio(@"C:\sounds\piano\A1.wav");
noteA1.Play();
```

i started my programm, pressed a key and boom! crashed with an error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Midi.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
It is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
```

Of course i didn't forget to use:

```
using System.Media;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
```

Right now i have no idea what can i do more and again - i need a help of an experienced person :)

Comment: I don't understand `Invoke` part, shouldn't you invoke `NoteOn`? What is `noteOnHandler`? How do you call `NoteOn`? From where?

Comment: There is a complete source i use:  [link](https://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2FGUIDemo)    I eddited form1.cs   and  the project depends on Midi folder also placed in the link above.

Comment: The program you are editing is expecting the user to press the play button on the windows Form. By using your midi keyboard you are effectively playing the note but also sending an event to the "NoteOn" method, which then triggers the second note when you call clock.Schedule. In summary, the program you are editing is probably not the right starting point for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: May i ask you Paul for any help with current code? Can you show me connection between 1) i pressed external midi key and 2) playButton_click ? Trying to understand the code, but can't find connection that doubles sounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [CL.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933648/242584), here is the sequence of events that is *probably* happening:

1. You push a key on your MIDI keyboard which sends out a `Note On message, with a Pitch of A0, and a velocity` (the exact velocity may vary every time).
2. Your code receives this and, since it matches your `if` statement, sends out a `Note On message, with a pitch of A0, and a velocity of 80`.

Here's where it gets tricky. Some MIDI devices send a corresponding `Note Off` message with the same Pitch when you release the key. Other devices will send a second `Note On` message with the same Pitch, but with a Velocity of 0. These two types of message are (or should be) functionally equivalent, and each device can do either to stop a note playing (or even both). So,

3. You release the key on your keyboard which sends out a `Note On message, with a Pitch of A0, and a Velocity of 0`.
4. Your code receives this and, since it also matches your `if` statement, sends out a `Note On message, with a pich of A0, and a velocity of 80`.

Since a Note On with a Velocity of 0 is also a Note Off, what happens is your code is turning your keyboard's "Note Off" back into a Note On, thus playing the sound twice.

As [Chris Dunaway suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933030/midi-dot-net-sounds-played-twice#comment49923622_30933648), you need to determine if a Note On is actually a "Note Off" by testing for a Velocity of 0.

```
    if (nutka == "A0" && msg.Velocity != 0) {
        clock.Schedule(new NoteOnMessage(outputDevice, Channel.Channel1, Pitch.A0, 80, 2));
    }
```

Comment: I would like to thank all of you guys and CL for specification!
But Dear Justin i would like to sincerely thank you!
You explained me exactly and in great detail my problem and you fixed it amazingly.
Now i understand step-by-step why it plays the sound twice and thanks to you now i can handle it.
It so great that there are people with a great practical knowledge and they share it with begginers like me :)

Comment: Is it possible to play a sound from Resources by the use of clock.Schedule?

Comment: @Martin I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're meaning to do. Please feel free to post another question with all the details of your new issue, and tag it as [midi].

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI 1.0 Detailed Specification says:

> MIDI provides two roughly equivalent means of turning off a note (voice). A note may be turned off either by sending a Note-Off message for the same note number and channel, or by sending a Note-On message for that note and channel with a velocity value of zero. The advantage to using "Note-On at zero velocity" is that it can avoid sending additional status bytes when Running Status is employed.
>
> Due to this efficiency, sending Note-On messages with velocity values of zero is the most commonly used method. However, some keyboard instruments implement release velocity where a Note-Off code (8nH) accompanied by a "velocity off" byte is used. A receiver must be capable of recognizing either method of turning off a note, and should treat them identically.

Comment: still can't figure it out, unfortunately i am not a logical mind :( need any helping hand :)

Comment: @Martin - I think you need to check `msg.Velocity` in your `NoteOn` method and if the Velocity is 0 then that is a note off (if I'm understanding what CL posted).